# UID env-var is not copied to Python's 'os.environ' dict

Tags: python

I have a Python script that needs to know the value of the $UID environment variable. The problem is, that for some reason, this variable does not exist in `os.environ`.

Below is an interactive demonstration - the $UID is defined on the shell, but although Python is launched from the same shell, the 'UID' environment variable does not exist in `os.environ`.

Is it a known problem? Is there anything to do about it?

```
$ echo $UID
1003
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['UID']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'UID'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's expected because `UID` is a [shell internal variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html). It is not propagated to subprocesses.

You have to get the values directly through the `os` module with `os.getuid()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`os.getuid()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.geteuid)